# Is there an android identification number that cannot be spoofed?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get a unique number of an android device that cannot be spoofed? I want to have my app locked down to only being able to be used on one device. My app appeals to root users however and i do not want to cut them out of the demographic. is there any information that cannot be spoofed with root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: No, because that can be spoofed with apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not finding an ID that cannot be spoofed. Spoofing can be stopped by first warning the user that they cannot fake their ID and any fake attempts will cause the app not to work. Doing that just as best practice. The best steps would be to get the device's MAC, Device ID, and other information that is supposed to be device unique. And then creating a HASH from it. A user could still circumvente by spoofing all of the same information, but most users choose to spoof random info.